# mySQL query Randomly takes a long time to execute

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, database-performance

I'm new to query optimization so I've read a lot of articles and watched YouTubes and stuff but I still can't figure it out.

The thing is I have this query that I want to execute for my API :

```
SELECT  req_id,follow_requests.insta_id as id,caption,follow_requests.male,
        users.name,users.profile_pic
    FROM  follow_requests
    INNER JOIN  users  ON follow_requests.insta_id = users.insta_id
    WHERE  (remaining_follow>0 && req_id<='574989')
      AND  NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT  *
            FROM  follows
            WHERE  follows.req_id=follow_requests.req_id
              AND  follows.follower_insta_id='3134816134'
    )
    ORDER BY  req_id DESC
    LIMIT  20
```

so I logged my database and digest showed that this one is eating +42% of my resources
some instance of this query look like 300 sec and it had an average of 20 sec!, (they got stuck on sending data status)
so I tried to change it for better (not that I really I know what I'm doing :)
and I changed it to this

```
SELECT  fr.req_id, fr.insta_id as id, fr.caption, fr.male, u.name,
        u.profile_pic, fr.date, fr.remaining_follow
    FROM  follow_requests AS fr
    INNER JOIN  users AS u  ON fr.insta_id=u.insta_id
    WHERE  fr.remaining_follow>0
      AND  fr.insta_id!=3134816134
      AND  NOT EXISTS 
    (
        SELECT  *
            FROM  follows as f
            WHERE  f.req_id=fr.req_id
              AND  f.follower_insta_id='3134816134'
    )
    ORDER BY  fr.date DESC
    LIMIT  20
```

the strange thing is, it was ok the first few runs! like from 0.1 sec till 0.7s
on test runs
but after I went to stretch a bit and came back to finalize it, this was also stuck for +200,300 sec but on sorting status this time
I checked query with explain and I noticed it's not using date index!
if only I remove 'order by' part from query it becomes really fast ~0.2s

any Ideas?

by the way, almost all columns are indexed and follow table has 2M rows other have a like +100k

sorry If I couldn't explain it well or I missed to give you some important info, I'm just new ;)

I would be very grateful if you could explain it in some way a newbie can understand while not missing out important details :)

Thanks in advance

=-=-=-=-=-=-= Update 1 =-=-=-=-=-=-=

Thanks to  all your help I reached this query now which is time efficient but
I had to change the whole thing a little but it might still  have a problem

```
SELECT  follow_requests.req_id, follow_requests.insta_id as id,
        caption, follow_requests.male, users.name,users.profile_pic
    FROM  follow_requests
    INNER JOIN  users  ON follow_requests.insta_id = users.insta_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  follows  ON follows.req_id = follow_requests.req_id
      AND  follows.follower_insta_id = '3134816134'
    WHERE  follow_requests.remaining_follow >0
      AND  follow_requests.insta_id != 3134816134
      AND  (follows.follower_insta_id != 3134816134 || follows.follower_insta_id is null)
    ORDER BY  follow_requests.date DESC
    LIMIT  20
```

hmm, first i need to say that i didnt write the orginal query (first 1) and i dont understand all of it myself :/ but the main programmer is out of reach right now and i have to take his place or the whole project will fail

about the problem is everybody can submit multiple requests for an insta_id but should only return one of them 
the main code and @Kickstart code (which is optimized version of the original one  with ave respond time of ~10 sec) does it right (for some reason I don't understand
but my code returns multiple instances of the same insta_id (with different req_id)

And alsocould some body enlighten me why the first query is doing so bad?

Comment: Your query is missing the _follows.req_id IS NULL_ check which is VERY important. A LEFT OUTER JOIN will try to do a join but still return a row even if no match is found, with the columns from the unmatched table being NULL. Hence if you do a LEFT OUTER JOIN then check for a column that must be there for being NULL then you are returning the rows from the first table where there is no match on the 2nd table.

Comment: @Kickstart yeah , i did it on purpose, i mean these two tables works like this, user 1 submits his request in follow_request , and user 2 can do it,user actions are submitted in follows , user 2 shouldn't see , user ones request again (can only fulfil it for each user one time), so why I'm keeping is null means it will not show request which no user has already fulfilled at least 1 time,but i need to show the to other users or they will never get done,but I'm not 100% sure if what I'm saying is correct or not ;)

Comment: Does `follows` have `INDEX(follower_insta_id, req_id)`?

Comment: Your query at the bottom of the question does a LEFT OUTER JOIN onto the follows table, checking that follower_insta_id = '3134816134'. So you will only get a matching row if that is true. As such you can just check in the WHERE clause for follower_insta_id  being NULL to exclude them - no need to check it != 3134816134

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really need to see the table declares and the EXPLAINs of the queries.

However it is possibly worth trying a LEFT OUTER JOIN of the follows table, and checking for no match (by checking for a column that must be populated on that table for being NULL).

However do you have an index on the follows table that covers both the req_id AND the follower_insta_id fields? Not 2 separate indexes, but one that covers both fields.

```
SELECT req_id,
        follow_requests.insta_id as id,
        caption,
        follow_requests.male,
        users.name,users.profile_pic 
FROM follow_requests 
INNER JOIN users ON follow_requests.insta_id = users.insta_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN follows ON follows.req_id = follow_requests.req_id AND follows.follower_insta_id = '3134816134'
WHERE follows.req_id IS NULL
AND remaining_follow > 0 
AND req_id <= '574989'
ORDER BY req_id DESC 
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: thanks a lot man, your request did it in like 17 sec , still high but the important part is it inspired me on how to write a better query, its time is optimised but something is still wrong, I'm on the way but I'll add an answer in like ~ 20 min and explain it more there , please have a look at it then

Comment: @question updated ? should i also add table structure and Explains?
and your query get faster with more limit , i mean limit 100 is faster than limit 20 , limit 100 search almost half row as limit 20 , says the explain, why?

Comment: I can't thank you enough for this, log show this query work like +1800 times! better now :), but where can i learn to query like that? any good youtube channels? useful links ?

Comment: Probably are some youtube channels but afraid I haven't looked through any to recommend. Best thing is just to look through questions on here that look interesting and see how people have answered them.

Comment: added another query that i can't fix, could you please help me with it? i did anything i could , @Kickstart

Answer (score 0):

I got 2 solutions

1ST:

instead of using "select *" use "select id"

```
SELECT fr.req_id, fr.insta_id as id, fr.caption, fr.male, u.name, u.profile_pic, fr.date, fr.remaining_follow
FROM follow_requests AS fr INNER JOIN users AS u 
ON fr.insta_id=u.insta_id
WHERE fr.remaining_follow>0 AND fr.insta_id!=3134816134 
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT f.id FROM follows as f WHERE f.req_id=fr.req_id AND f.follower_insta_id='3134816134')
ORDER BY fr.date DESC LIMIT 20
```

2ND:

you can can just it

```
SELECT fr.req_id, 
       fr.insta_id AS id, 
       fr.caption, 
       fr.male, 
       u.name, 
       u.profile_pic, 
       fr.date, 
       fr.remaining_follow 
FROM   follow_requests AS fr 
       INNER JOIN users AS u 
               ON fr.insta_id = u.insta_id 
       INNER JOIN follows AS f 
              ON f.req_id = fr.req_id 
                 AND f.follower_insta_id != '3134816134' 
WHERE  fr.remaining_follow > 0 
       AND fr.insta_id != 3134816134
ORDER  BY fr.date DESC 
LIMIT  20
```

Comment: thanks for reply, first one got stuck with starting status, 2nd one returns duplicates rows

Comment: Start a new Question; be sure to include `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and an explanation of what it is trying to find.

Comment: @SeyedMansourMirbehbahani how about you add a group by to remove the duplication

Comment: @fixed that problem ty